# How to scrape a table from a website using R

Tags: r

I am trying to scrape this table on the highest paid athletes but I am having trouble getting it to work like the other places I have scraped data from.

https://www.sportico.com/personalities/athletes/2022/100-highest-paid-athletes-in-the-world-2022-full-list-1234674901/

I have used rvest::read_html() to bring it in but then html_table() is usually my next step but that didnt work this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.sportico.com/personalities/athletes/2022/100-highest-paid-athletes-in-the-world-2022-full-list-1234674901/"
webpage <- read_html(url)
table <- html_table(html_nodes(webpage, "table")[[1]])
df <- data.frame(table)
```

Comment: I got "Error in html_nodes(webpage, "table")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds" when running the table <- line. Did it work for you?

Comment: Probably you need to remove `[[1]]`

Comment: Now `table` and `df` are both empty variables.